# Create a unique field base on the data input from other field in vtiger 6.0

Tags: php, module, vtiger

im new in vtiger and i really get a hard doing some custom module. Until i see and follow this tutorial http://community.vtiger.com/help/vtigercrm/developers/extensions/examples/entity-module.html.

I made a sample program to record the first name and last name of a certain person and base on the tutorial I made it. Now the scenario of my problem is something like this. What if want to make a new field where the value is the first 2 letters of my first name and and the first 2 letters of my last name ? So for example my name is John Doe, then the value of my custom field would be Jo-Do. It is my first time using vtiger and i dont have any idea where to start to make things work like this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the field created, you can use jquery to fullfill it, you can use the .val() function to get the name and the same to write it down

Comment: This is my first time to use vtiger can you please tell where will i put my javascript ? Coz when i create a costum module, there is no script included.

Comment: Sure, you can add it on "layouts/vlayout/modules/[name of your module]/resources/script.js?&v=6.0.0"

Comment: Thank you so much it seems this is what I want.

Comment: one thing I forgot, how will I call this script for it to run ? thank you.

Comment: if you call it Edit.js it will load automatically each time you visit the module

Comment: if this help you please select my answer